# Issue with ConstraintValidator on a field that contains a lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, annotations, java-8, hibernate-validator

Im trying to achieve a simple data validation on the output of a class field that contains a lambda expression. The validation is done using [a custom annotation and ConstraintValidator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html/ch06.html) as follows:

### Custom annotation :

```
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Documented
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MandatoryValidation.class)
public @interface Mandatory {

    boolean value() default true;

    String message() default "A value must be supplied";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

### Custom Validator :

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import com.google.common.base.Supplier;


public class MandatoryValidation implements ConstraintValidator<Mandatory, Supplier<String>> {

    private boolean mandatory;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Mandatory mandatory) {
        this.mandatory = mandatory.value();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Supplier<String> supplier, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

        if (mandatory && supplier.get() == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

### Class with field to be validated

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class SampleClass {

    private SampleGenerator generator;

    @Mandatory
    public Supplier<String> lambdaField = () -> generator.next();

}
```

My problem is that the above code generates one compilation error stating that
*"The annotation @Mandatory is disallowed for this data type."*

The error disappears if I remove the *"@Constraint(validatedBy = MandatoryValidation.class)"* line from my custom annotation, which leads me to think that I did screw up somewhere in the custom validator but i have no clue how to get it fixed.

Anyone can tell me what is wrong with the above code ?

### EDIT:

I'm using the following config :
**Jdk** :  jdk1.8.0_65
**javax.validation-api** : 1.1.0.Final
**hibernate-validator-annotation-processor** : 4.1.0.Final

As for the full compiler error message :
Error:(5, 5) java: The annotation @Mandatory is disallowed for this data type.

I've also noticed the following warning :
Warning:java: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.hibernate.validator.ap.ConstraintValidationProcessor' less than -source '1.8'.
This warning is removed if i switch to the 5.2.2.Final version of hibernate-validator-annotation-processor but the compilation error remains.

Comment: is `@Constraint` custom annotation? What is the definition of it?

Comment: It's a javax.validation annotation (the 1.1.0.Final version).

Comment: What's the full error and which JDK are you using for compilation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright this turned out to be one of the dumbest mistakes that i've managed to pull out to this date.
The Major screw up : the Supplier used in the Test class is of type *java.util.function.Supplier*, while the Supplier used in the custom validator is of type *com.google.common.base.Supplier*, hence the obvious compilation error. The second major screw up is that i didnt include complete imports in my question thinking that they would bloat up the post. Well that turned out to be a stupid decision.

**TLDR:** Messed up the imports, used wrong types, totally overlooked the explicit compilation error, went seeking help to my idiocy on stackoverflow.